# GitHub Action sqlfluff ("The path(s) ('models',) could not be accessed.")

Tags: python, sql, github, github-actions, sqlfluff

I have tried to add sqlfluff to the GitHub actions of a repository using these instructions (simply adding the file): https://github.com/sqlfluff/sqlfluff-github-actions/tree/main/menu_of_workflows/sunrise_movement

When pushing the branch with this new file to Git, the check actually shows up but keeps on failing returning "The path(s) ('models',) could not be accessed."

Does anyone know what this means and how to solve it?

Many thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> The path(s) ('models',) could not be accessed.

Verify if you really have a directory named `models`.

According to `sqlfluff lint` usage help:

```bash
$ sqlfluff lint --help
Usage: sqlfluff lint [OPTIONS] [PATHS]...

  Lint SQL files via passing a list of files or using stdin.

  PATH is the path to a sql file or directory to lint. This can be either a
  file ('path/to/file.sql'), a path ('directory/of/sql/files'), a single ('-')
  character to indicate reading from *stdin* or a dot/blank ('.'/' ') which
  will be interpreted like passing the current working directory as a path
  argument.
```

Comment: thx. Yeah, that's what you do when you run sqlfluff lint or fix in your terminal .... and it works. But the error I get is the GitHub action that runs sqlfluff ... I can't find any way to specify any path for this ..

Comment: @Alex: How are you running it then? You linked to a workflow (https://github.com/sqlfluff/sqlfluff-github-actions/blob/08bb9791e6fb1e6d1ffab95d9dc0a481af1550c8/menu_of_workflows/sunrise_movement/lint_models.yml#L16) which directly runs it through command line.

Comment: @Alex: In your attached screenshot, it's the same as that workflow i.e. running it from the command line. The only thing left with this is to check the `models` directly path which you can verify by `ls` command. You should add your directory structure and checkout step in your question.

Comment: You are right .. I had to remove the "models" from the .yml file where I specified the GitHub actions .... it basically ran "sqlfluff lint models" and I changed it to "sqlfluff lint" so that it simply lints all directories ... thx

Comment: @Alex: Right. So, you have a different directory structure. Good. Sure, no problem.